# A matlab code I don't understand

Tags: matlab

I don't understand what does mean `(1:65536 < wthresh)` in the command below :

```
cw = reshape(b(:)' .* (1:65536 < threshold), 256, 256);
```

b is an image of size 256x256 and 65536=256x256. I only know commands like this one:

```
cw = reshape(b(:)' .* (b < threshold), 256, 256);
```

meaning we keep only pixels of b that are smaller than 'threshold'.

Answer (score 4):

Just find out with easy examples:

```
>> (1:10<3)
ans =

   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This produces a vector where the first 2 elements are set to 1 while the rest are 0.

```
>> b=1:10
b =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

>> b.*(1:10<3)
ans =

   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This does an element-wise multiplication with vector `b`. So basically the first `threshold-1` elements are kept, while the rest are set to 0. `reshape` will rearrange the vector to a 256 x 256 matrix again.  Since I don't know the expected output, I cannot judge if this is the desired behavior, or if it is a bug in your code.

Comment: I took the liberty in editing your answer for grammatical fixes.  I hope you don't mind.  BTW, this is the correct interpretation of that code, so +1 for you.